# Get chrome tabs and windows from localStorage

Tags: json, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, local-storage

I am trying to access tabs and windows data inside a Google Chrome extension. I've apparently managed to get this info and loading it through localStorage but I don't know how to use the information, since I can't seem to parse the data back to arrays of objects through JSON parse.

Here's the code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>

tabs = {};
tabIds = [];

focusedWindowId = undefined;
currentWindowId = undefined;
localStorage.windowsTabsArray = undefined;

function loadItUp() {
  return arrays = chrome.windows.getAll({ populate: true }, function(windowList) {
    tabs = {};
    tabIds = [];
    var groupsarr = new Array();
    var tabsarr = new Array();
    var groupstabs = new Array();
    for (var i = 0; i < windowList.length; i++) {
      windowList[i].current = (windowList[i].id == currentWindowId);
      windowList[i].focused = (windowList[i].id == focusedWindowId);
      groupsarr[windowList[i].id] = "Untitled"+i;


      for (var j = 0; j < windowList[i].tabs.length; j++) {
        tabsarr[windowList[i].tabs[j].id] = windowList[i].tabs[j];
        groupstabs[windowList[i].id] = windowList[i].tabs;
      }
    }
      localStorage.groupsArray = JSON.stringify(groupsarr);
      localStorage.tabsArray = JSON.stringify(tabsarr);
      localStorage.groupsTabsArray = JSON.stringify(groupstabs);
  });
}

function addGroup() {
    var name = prompt("NEW_GROUP_NAME");
    var groupsarr = JSON.parse(localStorage.groupsArray);
    groupsarr.push(name);
    localStorage.groupsArray = JSON.stringify(groupsarr);
}

</script>
</head>
  <body onload="loadItUp()">
    WINDOW_QTY:
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var wArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.groupsArray);
        document.write(wArray);
    </script>
    <br/>
    TABS_QTY:
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var tArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.tabsArray)
        document.write(tArray);
    </script>
    <br/>
    WINDOWS_TABS_QTY:
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.write(JSON.parse(localStorage.groupsTabsArray));
    </script>
    <br/>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why do you need to put this info into `localStorage`, what are you trying to accomplish with that? What do you see on the page and in the error console when you "can't seem to parse the data back to arrays"? What do you expect? Do you realize that the document.write calls in <script> tags run before loadItUp()? Do you know about console.log?

Comment: I'm trying to make a tab grouping extension. The page shows bunch of [object Object]. The error console have no errors. I was expecting to grab an array of objects to work with. Had no idea that the page code was being executed before loadItUp(). Heard about console.log, but never used it.

Answer (score 0):

1)

> The page shows bunch of [object Object].

That's expected, objects are implicitly converted to string when you call `document.write(tArray);`; custom object without a custom `toString` implementation are converted to "[object Object]". It doesn't mean they're not "parsed".

To inspect the object you can use the Developer Tools. You can open the inspector for a background page from the Extensions page and if you get your page to open in a tab (e.g. if you use [chrome_url_overrides](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/override.html)) you can inspect it as you would inspect a regular web page.

If you replace the document.write calls with `console.log()`, you'll be able to inspect the objects in the Developer Tools' console.

2)

> > Do you realize that the document.write calls in  tags run before loadItUp()?
>
> Had no idea that the page code was being executed before loadItUp().

Scripts are executed at the moment they are inserted in the DOM by the parser (unless they are `defer`red or `async`) - see [MDC documentation on <script>](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/HTML/Element/Script), - while various load events, in particular `&lt;body onload=...>`, are executed after the page is finished parsing.

So right now your `document.write` calls print the values that were saved to `localStorage` the previous time the page was loaded, it's probably not what you wanted.

Instead of using `document.write()` from inline scripts, you should use [element.innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.innerHTML) or [element.textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Node.textContent) to update the page's text. There are many ways to get a reference to the element you need, [document.getElementById()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementById) is one.

3)

Last, note that not every object can be saved to and then loaded from `localStorage`. For example, methods will not survive the round-trip, and the identity of the object is not preserved, meaning that the object you got from a Chrome API will not be the same object after you store it in `localStorage` and load it back.

You have not explained why you think you need `localStorage` - it's used when you want to preserve some data after the page is closed and reloaded - so maybe you don't really need it?

Comment: Thanks for the instructions, Nickolay. I've researched this some more and found the answers. The console.log() tip was the best, thanks! Now about the functon loading before or after the document, i'm now following the tab extension sample that google disponibilize [here](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/samples.html#230463f2d5c3d4d0ca13c230e1f00f2aae0a8a64), it does everything i want to do, i'll just need to adapt the interface and add my desired functionalities.